# Stop wordpress caching URLs that match a pattern or if a user is logged in and cookie exists

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, .htaccess, caching

I host a wordpress site on apache / mysql with Hostinger. In addition to some posts and simple content pages there is a parent page `/members/` and child pages under it which are available only for logged in members, like so:

```
/members/
/members/lorem/
/members/ipsum/
/members/dolor/
```

I think it could be done with `.htaccess` is to check for a wordpress logged in cookie and set cache / expires headers to stop caching.

I'm looking for a way to use `.htaccess` to prevent caching of any pages with the word `member` in the URL. I've seen some examples that work using `<FilesMatch>` but they only check the filename and extension, not the whole URL to match a pattern before the filename. I've also seen that `<location>`, `<directory>` and `<directorymatch>` could be used but only if the host provider gives you server access to do so which I don't have.

I can't find a solution that works using the `.htaccess` file or a combination with wordpress and custom PHP.

My permalinks settings in wordpress is set to 'Post name' and my `.htaccess` file currently contains:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

**Note:** I don't want to use a plugin to do this for various reasons.

Answer (score 0):

I've figured it out. This is what worked in my `.htaccess` file

```
# BEGIN custom CACHE BUSTING
#<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    ## No ETags so cache headers work better
    #FileETag None
    #Header unset ETag

    ## Look for URLS starting with /member with anything after it, or containing login
    #RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^\/(member(.*)|(.*)login(.*))
    #RewriteRule ^ - [E=NOCACHE:1] ## Set our env variable
    #Header always set CHECK_NOCACHE "%{REDIRECT_NOCACHE}e" env=REDIRECT_NOCACHE ##custom header for testing, will show up if URL pattern matches above

    ## Do all cache busting, note NOCACHE is give a REDIRECT_ prefix, so have to read and check it by it's new name REDIRECT_NOCACHE
    #Header unset Pragma env=REDIRECT_NOCACHE
    #Header unset Cache-Control env=REDIRECT_NOCACHE
    #Header unset Last-Modified env=REDIRECT_NOCACHE
    #Header always set Pragma "no-cache" env=REDIRECT_NOCACHE
    #Header always set Cache-Control "s-maxage=0, max-age=0, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate" env=REDIRECT_NOCACHE
    #Header always set Expires "Thu, 1 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT" env=REDIRECT_NOCACHE
#</IfModule>
# END custom CACHE BUSTING
```